# Opencart : Getting twice alert on admin dashboard

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am getting twice alert after logged in opencart admin dashboard. I have debugged and found that it is happening due to ajax return. It returns the admin login page.

Ref image 1: 
[image]

Ref Image 2 : [image]

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the similar issue & later resolve it, actually there was problem with my website url. correct website url was containing `www(e.g- www.xyz.com)` but i miss it on both of my config file`(e.g- xyz.com)` due to which 
this issue was getting.